# Copy a range of filtered cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem copying data from a workbook to another.
The main file, `main_sheet`, collects data from a sheet from another workbook that changes its name by month and year, so currently `Workbookdecember18` (it is always protected by password).

From `Workbookdecember18`, I have to first filter the `code` column by `0` and then sort the `data3` column from `A` to `Z`. Then I have to copy the first 20 rows from `data1`, `data2` and `data3` into the `main_sheet` from another workbook.

This is the source sheet `Workbookdecember18`:

[image: This is the table]

This is the other workbook with `main_sheet` (it will normally have only 20 rows):

[image]

This is the code I've written but it doesn't work:

```
Windows("Workbookdecember18").Activate
Sheets("1").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$CH$2402").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
Range("D3").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range(D3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("A2:D30").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Another workbook").Activate
Range("A2:D30").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The first problem is that I have to make it recognise the workbook when its name changes each month and make it select the 20 rows I need (even though the last one may be on row 200 after it's filtered).

Comment: Is this the code you are actually using? Because there is a missing quotation marks which is also the reason your code highlighting is wrong. You need to edit `.Add Key:=Range(D3")` to `.Add Key:=Range("D3")`

Comment: I had to edit the code for this example, it doesn't actually do what I need.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For the next three or four weeks, `"Workbook" & Format(Date, "mmmmyy")` should produce *WorkbookDecember18* in a US-EN regional locale.

```
Option Explicit

Sub filterAndTransfer()
    Dim target As Range

    Windows("Another workbook").Activate

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    Windows("Workbook" & Format(Date, "mmmmyy")).Activate

    With Worksheet("1")
        .Unprotect
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
            .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, "D"), Order1:=xlDescending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=0
            .Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=target
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```